# How to exit Ansible playbook when there are multiple hosts defined in the playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a sample Ansible playbook s.yml:

```
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug: msg="{{ var }}"

    - debug: msg="Do a INFLATE"
      when: var == "inflate"

    - meta: end_play
      when: var == "inflate"

    - debug: msg="this is a DEFLATE"
      when: var == "deflate"

- hosts: bat

  tasks:

  - debug: msg="{{ hostname }}"
```

Basically, I want it to handle two conditions: inflate and deflate. If it is inflate, it will run some tasks and then exit(where the end_play is). If it is deflate, it will do something on a different hosts(bat in this sample which has wag-bat and dsg-bat).

When I run it for deflate:

```
$ ansible-playbook s.yml -e "var=deflate"

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:06:50 +0000 (0:00:00.022)       0:00:00.022 ************ 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:06:51 +0000 (0:00:01.032)       0:00:01.055 ************ 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "deflate"
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:06:51 +0000 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:01.078 ************ 
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [meta] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:06:51 +0000 (0:00:00.021)       0:00:01.100 ************ 
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:06:51 +0000 (0:00:00.015)       0:00:01.116 ************ 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "this is a DEFLATE"
}

PLAY [bat] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:06:51 +0000 (0:00:00.040)       0:00:01.156 ************ 
ok: [wag-bat]
ok: [dsg-bat]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:06:53 +0000 (0:00:01.549)       0:00:02.706 ************ 
ok: [wag-bat] => {
    "msg": "wag-bat"
}
ok: [dsg-bat] => {
    "msg": "dsg-bat"
}
```

It skipped the end_play and went on to bat and displayed the hostname which is defined in the /etc/ansible/host_vars/wag-bat and /etc/ansible/host_vars/dsg-bat files. This is what I want.

But when I run it for inflate:

```
$ ansible-playbook s.yml -e "var=inflate"

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:11:55 +0000 (0:00:00.021)       0:00:00.021 ************ 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:11:56 +0000 (0:00:01.017)       0:00:01.039 ************ 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "inflate"
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:11:56 +0000 (0:00:00.022)       0:00:01.062 ************ 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Do a INFLATE"
}

TASK [meta] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:11:56 +0000 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:01.085 ************ 

PLAY [bat] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:11:56 +0000 (0:00:00.018)       0:00:01.103 ************ 
ok: [dsg-bat]
ok: [wag-bat]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 22 May 2022  21:11:58 +0000 (0:00:02.131)       0:00:03.234 ************ 
ok: [wag-bat] => {
    "msg": "wag-bat"
}
ok: [dsg-bat] => {
    "msg": "dsg-bat"
}
```

It seems it did go through the end_play, however it did not exit the execution of the playbook but continued to get on to bat. If I remove the `- hosts: bat` portion from the playbook, it will stop at the end_play for inflate.

If there a way I can make it to stop at the end_play for inflate? I do need to have the `- hosts: bat` to handle the deflate part. I tried to use include_tasks to handle the deflate part, but I can not define the `-hosts bat` in the sub playbook.

Comment: Maybe you should just have two separate playbooks, one for "inflate" and one for "deflate". Then you don't need to worry about conditionals, and you can have the multiple plays you require for the "deflate" process without having to worry about them for "inflate".

Comment: You can of course add a `when:` condition to the tasks in the second play (or wrap them in a `block:` with a the appropriate conditional).

Comment: @larsks I could separate the code into two playbooks, but I have to create two jobs(in jenkins) which the users will need to get used to. So I will prefer to have them in one job and give user the choice. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I tried the ```block``` with the condition and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@larsks suggested to use `block` and it worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: If you feel like your question deserves a self answer, please add the resulting code. The above is far from sufficient to understand what you have done to fix the issue.